# How to check for hyperlink through Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, hyperlink, webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber

I'm working with Selenium Webdriver on Eclipse, and I want to access the hyperlink for forget password:

```
<p class="mt15 text-center fs-12 forgot-password-links"><a href="forgotpassword.htm" class="text-blue text-capitalize text-center">Forgot Password?</a></p>
```

I've tried using linkText, partialLinkTest as well as WebElement. Nothing seems to work so far. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your binding lanuage ? and what is the error you are getting with `linkText` , `partialLinkText ` ?

Comment: Can you share what you tried so far?

Comment: @Then("^user clicks on Forgot Password$")
 public void user_clicks_on_Forgot_Password(String href) throws Throwable {
   WebElement openLinks = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='form-container-left']"));
   
   for(int i = 1; i < openLinks.findElements(By.tagName("a")).size(); i++) {
    String openLink = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ENTER);
    openLinks.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i).sendKeys(openLink);
   }
 }

Answer (score 0):

According to the HTML you provided that element can be located with the following XPath:

```
//a[@href='forgotpassword.htm']
```

or if you prefer cssSelector

```
a[href='forgotpassword.htm']
```